# Java Scanner Class - Unable to exit while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner, break

I am trying to create a simple Scanner test program which will exit once the user inputs "Quit".

I have the variable being output to console and it will output Quit but when I am trying to compare the variable to the raw string it doesn't see it as true.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input;
    Scanner sc;

    System.out.println("Enter 'Quit' to exit.");

    while (true) {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = sc.nextLine();
        if (input == "Quit") {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(input);
    }

    sc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare strings with `equals()`method not with `==` operator

```
if (input.equals( "Quit")) {
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you :D why does "==" not work?

Comment: @TheShinyTuxedo == operator is used to compare the objects

Comment: == will compare the references of the objects that's why it doesn't work to compare.

Answer (score 1):

Use always  equals to compare the Strings.

`==` will compare the references.